# error_reporting E_STRICT causes white screen of death

Tags: php, fatal-error, error-reporting

I've looked around at a few different postings but haven't been able to find an answer to my problem. Recently I realized I wasn't using E_STRICT in my error_reporting, so I added error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT) and have been going through debugging errors that I find.

The problem I am facing now is with error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT) some of the pages won't load at all, I am given a white screen with no errors and no information as to what is wrong. If I use simply error_reporting(E_ALL) from the error_reporting everything loads fine..

I have the same error_reporting set up in my php.ini as well as my website.

**I was also able to figure out exactly where the script was breaking (on an include_once for a file that does exist.)**

I suppose I could survive with just using E_ALL as I have been up until now, but I am curious as to what the major problems are. Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Do you have the ini setting `display_errors` on?

Comment: Yes & I have been receiving errors, there are just a few pages that white screen

Comment: Are you using output buffering?

Comment: Do you mean like ob_start? If so, yes but always followed by an ob_end_clean (I searched the whole site)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm concerned, the errors may be stored in the same directory in a file called `error_log`. My website host turned the reporting feature off, and all the errors are stored in the `error_log` file.

Completely based on experience.

Comment: WELL, I refreshed my folder and low and behold there is my error_log hiding in plain sight! I found the culprit causing issues! Why do only some of the errors appear in the browser as PHP Errors?

Comment: @Corey What I think is that if the errors are fatal or warnings, they are not displayed, or it has something to do with your `error_reporting` configuration.

Comment: @Corey Also, can you please accept my answer if it helped you? Just click the white tick underneath the vote counts on my question. Thanks.

Comment: The thing is I am still receiving the majority of the errors, i'd say almost if not all of the errors preceding this did appear in the browser. In regards to accepting your answer, I want to see if anyone can explain to me why they aren't appearing in the browser. I'll give you +1 (Actually I don't have enough reputation, sorry) and i'll accept if you or someone else can explain why (or if no one does).

Comment: @Corey The StackOverflow community is always very friendly, and will be eager to help you with any question you need to ask, including the one you've mentioned to me.

Comment: @Corey You also don't seem to have enough reputation to upvote.

Comment: Actually I think i know why it isn't showing up, I think JAXL is catching all the errors (probably what Peter Kiss was talking about) - Accepted your answer

Comment: Thank you very much. Always happy to help with further questions.